# Upload file to a certain account on Dropbox

Tags: upload, sdk, dropbox

I want to upload a file with php to dropbox.

For that i downloaded the Dropbox sdk but i dont see a possibility to
upload the file to a certain account (the account which made the Dropbox app).
Its just possible to upload the file to the account of the current user.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the most common use of the Dropbox API, but it's possible to just use a single account. Once you auth an account, you get back an access token, which you use in your code to call the Dropbox API. Files will get uploaded to whatever account the access token is for. So all you need to do is auth your own account once and then hardcode that access token.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea. I tried:

```
$json = array(

        "key"=> "myKey",
        "secret"=> "mysecret"
);


$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJson($json);
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accessToken = "AccessTokenIReceived by the link: $authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();";


$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
$accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

print_r($accountInfo);

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/working-draft.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);

$folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/");
print_r($folderMetadata);

$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "w+b");
$fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getFile("/working-draft.txt", $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($fileMetadata);
```

But i always receive the Error Message:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dropbox\Exception_InvalidAccessToken' 
and
Dropbox\Exception_InvalidAccessToken: HTTP status 401 {"error": "The given OAuth 2 access token doesn't exist or has expired."}

Comment: When using your own account, you have to use the "Generated access token" on the app page. The process will generate a token, but the token will always be invalid.